# Django - Why is this TableView not ordering the queryset?

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I have a TableView in a Django project which isn't properly ordering its queryset. I tried adding the ordering to the model Meta, overriding the view's get_queryset method, and don't know how best to tackle this. This doesn't happen in any other view, I have many views with many different models, and usually overriding the "get_queryset" method works fine, and I can order however I need there, but right now it isn't working in this particular view.

The view looks like this:

```
class ShippingCenterPricesTableView(PurchaseViewingPermissionMixin, PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = ShippingCenterPriceHistory
    table_class = ShippingCenterPricesTable
    template_name = 'purchases/shipping_center/shipping_center_prices_table.html'
    filter_class = ShippingCenterPriceFilter
    export_name = "PreciosCentrosDeEmbarque"
    formhelper_class = ShippingCenterPriceFormHelper
    paginate_by = 100000000

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShippingCenterPricesTableView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['allows_shipping_center_creation'] = self.request.user.purchases_permission == '2'
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ShippingCenterPricesTableView, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.order_by('-date')
        return qs
```

The model looks like this:

```
class ShippingCenterPriceHistory(models.Model):
    shipping_center = models.ForeignKey(ShippingCenter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='Centro de embarque')
    circular_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Precio circular sin I.V.A.', null=False, blank=False)
    differenced_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Precio diferenciado', null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha actualización', auto_now_add=True)
    observations = models.CharField(verbose_name='Observaciones', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    current = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Precio actual', default=True)

    @property
    def discount_percentage(self):
        return 1 - (self.differenced_price / self.circular_price)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)
```

And, in case it's relevant, the Table looks like this:

```
class ShippingCenterPricesTable(Table):
    date = tables.columns.Column(empty_values=(), verbose_name='Fecha actualización', orderable=True)

    def render_date(self, record):
        return record.date

    class Meta:
        model = ShippingCenterPriceHistory
        fields = ('shipping_center', 'circular_price', 'differenced_price', 'date', 'current',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShippingCenterPricesTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.user.purchases_permission != '2':
            self.exclude = ('actions',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify ordering with an attribute in the Table.Meta `order_by = '-date'`

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#Table.Meta

```
class ShippingCenterPricesTable(Table):

    class Meta:
        model = ShippingCenterPriceHistory
        fields = ('shipping_center', 'circular_price', 'differenced_price', 'date', 'current',)
        order_by = '-date'
```